# Gridlines in Excel exported as .htm

Tags: php, html, excel, publish

This possibly has not much to do with programming, but I hope someone can shed some light to this issue for me.

I have some Excel spreadsheets with football statistics; I wanted to share them on my site. So I published Excel tables as .htm pages.

When I upload a page to my site, it looks exactly like in Excel, example here:

https://www.betgps.com/England-Premier-League/content/E0-match01.htm

However, when I use php include function to insert that table in website template, I get some ugly gridlines; here is that same table, you can see majority of grey vertical gridlines:

https://www.betgps.com/England-Premier-League/football-match-19825554-rvrt-255.php

It's that same table, I just used this code to display it:

```
<?php include('England-Premier-League/content/E0-match01.htm'); ?>
```

I tried to use **require** instead of **include**, it didn't work.

I tried to convert .htm file to .php file, but it didn't work either.

I tried to set white color of gridlines in Excel before publishing, it didn't work.

Can somebody help with this annoying issue, please, why are gridlines not displayed in direct link to .htm file, but are displayed when that same file is embedded to another page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried in your style sheet (CSS) to set: `td, tr { border-style: none }`

Comment: I have just tried, and it doesn't work, either. But I think you are on the right track, as I see that .htm file itself has inline style (<style id="E0_13153_Styles">, and then there are countless border/border-top/etc. properties, and they have exactly that grey gridline colour, #D9D9D9. But it's pity that htm file itself does not display those gridlines, and when I include it in main template, which has its own css, they get displayed. I will try to explore this further, thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Well, I resolved it, you were right - in my main css there was a class "table", and .htm file exported from Excel, of course, had the class of the same name, so it got applied as soon as I moved file from "independent" into template. So, I removed the gridlines; thank you once again for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed!